# Sass не видит переменную

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
@import: '_fonts.sass'
@import: '_variables.sass'

*
 margin: 0
 padding: 0

.main__wrapper
 width: 100%
 display: flex
 justify-content: center

//header

header
 margin: 0 2.64%
 display: flex
 justify-content: space-between
 .header__right-info
  color: white
  .right-info__light-menu
   display: block
   img
    display: inline-block
   ul
    display: inline-block
    li
     display: inline-block
     a
      text-decoration: none
      color: $black_color
```

Вот таким способом подключаю файл с переменными. При компиляции вот такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл `_variables.sass` лежит в той же папке, что и `style.sass`

Присваивание переменной:

```css
$lato : 'Lato';
$pt : 'PT';

$text_color : rgb( 10, 13, 16 );
$text_white_color : #f1f0f0;
$red_color : #c61b2b;
$black_color : #0a0d10;

/**/
$xs: 0px;
$sm: 575px;
$md: 767px;
$lg: 991px;
$xl: 1199px;


body
 color:black
```

Скриншот настроек компилятора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: код присвоения переменной добавьте сюда.

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, готово

Comment: Если другие переменные видит, проверьте переменные на кирилица/латиница

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, не помогает

Comment: @Дмытрык, другие тоже не видит

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, не помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@import: '_fonts.sass'
@import: '_variables.sass'
```

После @import двоеточие не нужно.